# ​Automatically include relevant links for the tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can SO include relevant links for each tags. ​There could be multiple links for a specific tag. It would save the user from googling or juggle their memory.
E.g, ​If the tag is ExtJs it would be http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/, for jQuery it could be http://jquery.com/ etc.
The links can be shown in a section right underneath the tags.

Comment: How does that relate to tag-wikis and excerpts?

Answer (score 5):

There's already a tag wiki for most of the popular tags on Stack Overflow, where users can add relevant information and links. Just click on the tag and look for the "learn more..." tab to go to the tag wiki.

Examples:

- [ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/extjs/info)
- [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

This is where users should look when they need very broad information about a topic. Most of the wikis for programming languages and other popular tags provide a good "getting started" point for people who are new to a technology.